# Unity: Diagonal movement not corresponding to correct key inputs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, direction, diagonal

I've been trying to find a solution for this issue for a while now with no luck.

I want to be able to move in 8 directions but for some odd reason, my player only wants to move in 6 directions.

When I press:

- W+D or W+A, it moves towards the top right.
- S+D or S+A, it moves towards the bottom left.

The vertical and horizontal movements work perfectly fine. It's just two of the four diagonal movements which are being a pain.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControllerTest : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed;

    private Animator anim;
    private Rigidbody2D playerRigidbody;

    private bool playerMoving;
    public Vector2 lastMove;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        playerMoving = false;

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.5f)

            {
                playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, playerRigidbody.velocity.y);
                playerMoving = true;
                lastMove = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f);
            }

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < -0.5f)

            {
                playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(playerRigidbody.velocity.y, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed);
                playerMoving = true;
                lastMove = new Vector2(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
            }

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0.5f && Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > -0.5f)

            {
                playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0f, playerRigidbody.velocity.y);
            }

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < 0.5f && Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > -0.5f)

            {
                playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(playerRigidbody.velocity.x, 0f);
            }

        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
        anim.SetFloat("MoveY", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        anim.SetBool("PlayerMoving", playerMoving);
        anim.SetFloat("LastMoveX", lastMove.x);
        anim.SetFloat("LastMoveY", lastMove.y);
    }
}
```

This is the basic code that I used for my character movement. If someone could help me fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Redza

Comment: The mistake was with the code in the second "if" statement. I should have used playerRigidbody.velocity.x instead of playerRigidbody.velocity.y. Oopsies.

Answer (score 3):

The whole logic seems strange to me, I would make a single vector of movement

```
 playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed);
```

unless there are some other concerns.

It's possible that with so many conditions only last 2 of 4 are end being applied.

Comment: Though I'm glad, I'm kind of embarassed to admit that I found the problem. I accident used "playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(playerRigidbody.velocity.y, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed);". When it actuality, it should have been playerRigidbody.velocity.x.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was with the code in the second "if" statement. I should have used playerRigidbody.velocity.x instead of playerRigidbody.velocity.y. Oopsies.